# Uppercase for textfield

Tags: html, gridview, uppercase, ext.net

HTML

```
style='text-transform:uppercase'
```

tried this but it change the label of the text box. I want to make the letter upper case in the input box not the label.
And after save it it will appear in grid view.Thank you

Comment: Need more info, add code showing the the textbox location, is it in the grid or outside, in any case FieldStyle property is the one to set if you want to change the style of the field it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a style just to the field use:

```
FieldStyle="text-transform:uppercase"
```

However, that is going to make the whole field uppercase.  I prefer a renderer like in the grids, but you could use a listener to overwrite the field value.  Either way the processing is on the client side, no round trips.

```
<ext:TextField ID="TextFieldUC" runat="server" FieldLabel="Name with UC First" EnableKeyEvents="true">
     <Listeners>
         <KeyPress Handler="#{TextFieldUC}.setValue( #{TextFieldUC}.getValue().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + #{TextFieldUC}.getValue().slice(1)  )" Delay="33" />
     </Listeners>
</ext:TextField>
```

Comment: i tried the renderer in grid and it works but do you know if using the same code can i make the whole field uppercase? Thanks

Comment: if you want the whole field uppercase I would just apply 'text-transform:uppercase' to the style in the grid.